# R from character to numeric

Tags: r, csv, character-encoding, xts

I have this csv file (fm.file):

```
Date,FM1,FM2
28/02/2011,14.571611,11.469457
01/03/2011,14.572203,11.457512
02/03/2011,14.574798,11.487183
03/03/2011,14.575558,11.487802
04/03/2011,14.576863,11.490246
```

And so on.

I run this commands:

```
fm.data <- as.xts(read.zoo(file=fm.file,format='%d/%m/%Y',tz='',header=TRUE,sep=','))
is.character(fm.data)
```

And I get the following:

```
[1] TRUE
```

How do I get the fm.data to be numeric without loosing its date index. I want to perform some statistics operations that require the data to be numeric.

Answer (score 2):

I was puzzled by two things: It didn't seem that that 'read.zoo' should give you a character matrix, and it didn't seem that changing it's class would affect the index values, since the data type should be separate from the indices. So then I tried to replicate the problem and get a different result:

```
txt <- "Date,FM1,FM2
28/02/2011,14.571611,11.469457
01/03/2011,14.572203,11.457512
02/03/2011,14.574798,11.487183
03/03/2011,14.575558,11.487802
04/03/2011,14.576863,11.490246"
require(xts)
fm.data <- as.xts(read.zoo(file=textConnection(txt),format='%d/%m/%Y',tz='',header=TRUE,sep=','))
is.character(fm.data)
#[1] FALSE

 str(fm.data)
#-------------
An ‘xts’ object from 2011-02-28 to 2011-03-04 containing:
  Data: num [1:5, 1:2] 14.6 14.6 14.6 14.6 14.6 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "FM1" "FM2"
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ tclass: chr [1:2] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
 $ tzone : chr ""
```

zoo- and xts-objects have their data in a matrix accessed with `coredata` and their indices are a separate set of attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you have some dirty data in you csv file. In other words FM1 or FM2 columns contain a character, somewhere, that stops it being interpreted as a numeric column. When that happens, XTS (which is a matrix underneath) will force the whole thing to character type.

Here is one way to use R to find suspicious data:

```
s <- scan(fm.file,what="character")
# s is now a vector of character strings, one entry per line
s <- s[-1]  #Chop off the header row
all(grepl('^[-0-9,.]*$',s,perl=T)) #True means all your data is clean
s[ !grepl('^[-0-9,.]*$',s,perl=T) ]
which( !grepl('^[-0-9,.]*$',s,perl=T) ) + 1
```

The second-to-last line prints out all the csv rows that contain characters you did not expect. The last line tells you which rows in the file they are (+1 because we removed the header row).

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use `read.csv` and then convert the first column to an `Date` object using `as.Date`

```
> x <- read.csv(fm.file, header=T)
> x$Date <- as.Date(x$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
> x
        Date      FM1      FM2
1 2011-02-28 14.57161 11.46946
2 2011-03-01 14.57220 11.45751
3 2011-03-02 14.57480 11.48718
4 2011-03-03 14.57556 11.48780
5 2011-03-04 14.57686 11.49025
```